# ejabberd How to use MUC/SUB with xmppframework

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

We are using ejabberd 17.01 for an iOS and Android application.

We need to create a persistent room where user shall be able to receive messages while they are not connected / joined in the room.

We think ejabberd has the solution for that.

How to configure that in XMPPFramework in iOS and smack in Android SMACK library?

Answer (score 2):

We implemented an `XMPPMUCSub` module in a fork of XMPPFramework at https://github.com/Digithurst/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/MUC-Sub/XMPPMUCSub.h

You setup this module like any other in XMPPFramework and then subscribe users to rooms with the subscribe method.

```
- (nullable NSString *)subscribe:(nonnull XMPPJID *)user to:(nonnull XMPPJID *)room 
                        nick:(nullable NSString *)nick password:(nullable NSString *)pass;
```

Events will then start flowing through the `XMPPMUCSubDelegate`.